# Why does Postgres select return wrong floating point calculation?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Why does `SELECT 2 * 4 * ( 5 / 2) * 4` return `64` instead of `80`?

The real query I'm running looks like this:

```
SELECT 2 * equity_gains_score * (tenure_score / 2) * investor_score AS propensity
```

but I had the same result when I ran it substituting numbers for columns. How can I fix this statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres does *integer* division.  So, `5/2` is `2` rather than `2.5`.

You can just add a decimal point to one of the operands of the division:

```
SELECT 2 * 4 * ( 5 / 2.0) * 4
```

Or convert a value to a numeric:

```
SELECT 2 * 4 * ( 5::numeric / 2.0) * 4
```

Note:  If you want an integer as the result, then you need to convert back to an integer:

```
SELECT (2 * 4 * ( 5 / 2.0) * 4)::int
```